# Possible to disable autop temporarily?

Tags: wp-autop

If I disable autop entirely, I need to add `<p>` everywhere I want a paragraph. Is it possibe to disable autop temporarily? Like in a shortcode

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can deactivate the autop for shortcode via filter

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I do the following, which I grabbed from a plugin at some point in the past.

Add the function below to functions.php and use the two tags

`<!-- noformat on -->` and `<!-- noformat off -->`

in your page/post editor, i.e.

```
        text will be rendered *with* autop

        <!-- noformat on -->

        text will be rendered *without* autop

        <!-- noformat off -->

        text will be rendered *with* autop
```

Content outside of the two format tags will have autop enabled, as noted.

**The function:**

```
// <!-- noformat on --> and <!-- noformat off --> functions

function newautop($text)
{
    $newtext = "";
    $pos = 0;

    $tags = array('<!-- noformat on -->', '<!-- noformat off -->');
    $status = 0;

    while (!(($newpos = strpos($text, $tags[$status], $pos)) === FALSE))
    {
        $sub = substr($text, $pos, $newpos-$pos);

        if ($status)
            $newtext .= $sub;
        else
            $newtext .= convert_chars(wptexturize(wpautop($sub)));      //Apply both functions (faster)

        $pos = $newpos+strlen($tags[$status]);

        $status = $status?0:1;
    }

    $sub = substr($text, $pos, strlen($text)-$pos);

    if ($status)
        $newtext .= $sub;
    else
        $newtext .= convert_chars(wptexturize(wpautop($sub)));      //Apply both functions (faster)

    //To remove the tags
    $newtext = str_replace($tags[0], "", $newtext);
    $newtext = str_replace($tags[1], "", $newtext);

    return $newtext;
}

function newtexturize($text)
{
    return $text;   
}

function new_convert_chars($text)
{
    return $text;   
}

remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
add_filter('the_content', 'newautop');

remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
add_filter('the_content', 'newtexturize');

remove_filter('the_content', 'convert_chars');
add_filter('the_content', 'new_convert_chars');
```